# Give specific name for uploadable files

Tags: php, file, file-upload

I have this code, to upload multiple files.

I would like to add a custom name for each file, beacuse i will store them in sql like this:

filename-1-2017-05-02-12:30:00 (1 is the actual array index, and after a date time)

```
    if(isset($_POST['submitButton']))
{
    if(isset($_FILES['gallery']))
    {
        if($_FILES["gallery"]["size"] > 0 )
        {
            foreach($_FILES['gallery']["name"] AS $key=>$file)
            {
                if($_FILES['gallery']['size'][$key]  != 0 )
                {
                    $target_path = "../documents/";
                    $target_path = $target_path . $_FILES['gallery']['name'][$key];

                    printr($_FILES['gallery']);
                    die();

                    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['gallery']['tmp_name'][$key], $target_path))
                    {
                        //$file_name = basename($_FILES['dok_file']['name']);
                        header("Location: ".$host."/".$admin_folder."/feltoltott-fajlok.php?new=1");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $error[] = "A fájl feltöltése nem sikerült, próbálja újra.";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is as simple as concatenating the date to the filename(s). Surely you can Google that.

Comment: Not really connected to OP's question, but don't you think that one should avoid `:` or any special character in a file name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
$target_path = "../documents/" . $_FILES['gallery']['name'][$key] . "-$key-" . date( "Y-m-d-H:i:s" );
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['gallery']['tmp_name'][$key], $target_path );
```

Comment: This doesnt add that the files name. If i print_r the files array, i get the same name, as the file name is.

Comment: And how can i give a variable for each files? I want to save them into an sql table.